# When to delete a keyword from an advertising campaign?

Tags: econometrics, marketing

I use a pay per click program to advertise one of my products. You pay different amounts for different clicks on keyword searches based on supply and demand.

I get the following data for each keyword:
Impressions
Click through rate
Conversion rate
Number of conversions
Total Sales $
Cost of a click

It's easy enough to order the keywords by profitability using the following formula:

($Sales*Gross Profit Margin)-Ad Spend = Gross Profit Per Keyword

However, I'm trying to decide my cutoff for when I should delete a keyword from the campaign. Obviously if it's profitable it's ok, however for those that aren't profitable, when have they "proven" that they're going to remain so?

I think it would be economically infeasible to let each keyword be clicked on 120 times to establish normal distribution etc. For example, in most cases, more than 10 clicks without a sale means that even if you make a sale on the 11th click, you'll still be in the red. So where should I draw the line?